# I cant see any servers on cs go

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

I click refresh on the server list, I have re-downloaded the game multiple times, and I have also reset the filters, but still no servers appear to be available.

However, there are 4 servers on my history that I can join, 1 of which is locked.

Does anyone know how I can make it so that more servers are available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your game legal (from steam)? Sorry to ask this but this might help us very much.

Comment: @ardaozkal, pirated copies of Counter-Strike: Global Offensive can view the servers (in the server browser), but not connect to them. When connecting, they only get kicked for not having a valid user credentials and/or VAC enabled; a DRM and username check. | And yes, I [do own CS:GO](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/games) somewhere in that list.

Comment: You could always try going down to the notification area, and then right clicking steam, servers, and then you can find servers for CS:GO. I've had to do it before.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Arqade,

About your problem, 
It might be about your internet connection.

I think that changing your max ping will (partially) solve this, to do that, go into Settings - Gameplay - set Max Acceptable Matchmaking Ping slider to a higher value.

Setting max ping will show more games but, It'll also make you laggier in-game, so be sure not to set that more than 150, 150+ is dangerous (people can headshot you easily) but 150- kinda safe though, I personally love playing in servers in my country and I get 14 ms ping, which is awesome. Btw. after 300 ms ping, you usually can't even move.

Answer (score 0):

Well there could be many reasons why nothing is showing up. The two main easy fixes are to check your filters on the server list. Secondly it might be because of your internet, I had this problem for many months, but after upgrading my internet a huge flowing river of servers popped up. Hopefully this could help you :D